# ODP.NET - Division by zero?

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I'm trying to fill a datatable, but the dataadapter returns an exeption: OverflowExeption (Division by Zero). This is my commandtext:

```
select value1/value2 from table
```

The datatype of value1 und value2 is NUMBER in the database. None of these values are 0.

What is the problem with this division?

greetings naked man

Answer (score 5):

Division by zero is the most common cause of a numeric overflow, but other values can also cause it.

If you divide one number by a very small number, the result gets very large. If the result is larger than what the data type can represent, you get an overflow error.

Comment: Maybe the result has decimal precision which exceeds the limit for the corresponding .net datatype so maybe a trunc to the relevant number of digits should work in this case

Comment: Nice! trunc workes. I think .Net converts NUMBER into DECIMALand DECIMALcan only handle a smaller count of digits than NUMBER.

Comment: @NackterMannMitHut: I think that it may be a side effect of the added code. Reducing precision is normally an expected effect of converting to a different data type, and should not cause an exception. An arithmetic overflow is by definition when a value is larger in magnitude than the destination can handle, it never happens because the precision is higher than the destination can handle.